# dlib code written in QtCreator in windows does not exits while qt mainwindow has been exited

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, dlib

well I am developing image processing applications in qt and dlib and opencv 
but when in a qtwidget application where i coded after i run the code and everything is fine when the code finishes and *i hit the close button of qt mainwindow the mainwidow closes but the application does not i have to manually stop the code*
it happens when a dlib related code has been ran in the app
about the code i just open a webcam and do face detection

```
while(frame_counter<100)
{
cv::Mat temp;
cap >> temp;
cv_image<bgr_pixel> cimg(temp);
full_object_detection shape;
std::vector<dlib::rectangle> faces = detector(cimg);
std::vector<full_object_detection> shapes;
for (unsigned long i = 0; i < faces.size(); ++i)
           {
shape = pose_model(cimg, faces[i]);
}
win.clear_overlay();
win.set_image(cimg);
win.add_overlay(render_face_detections(shape));
}
```

**I don't know why it happens  any idea?**

Answer (score 0):

If you have this line in your code:

```
while()
{
}
```

Then it will never break out of the loop, you need some sort of event driven code. You need ot ditch your single loop and instead use timer ticks or events to drive your camera capture code and then an event for QApplication::quit()

```
void frmMain::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *) {
    QApplication::quit();
}
```

Comment: I have something to get out of the while loop actually after showing 100 frames it will get out of while loop,and if i add the quit(),the mainwindow closes but the process still runing